# Ncurses: Creating padded spaces between columns

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, curses

I am creating a scrollable list using ncurses, similar to the list in `aptitude` (apt-get front end).

How should I go about creating padded spaces between columns?  I am planning to write each column using `wprintw()`.

e.g.

```
pizza      spicy      10
steak      normal     10
burritoes  guacamole  20
```

each line using wprintw().

Comment: Do you mean something like "\t\t"?

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you 2 space padded, left justified, string columns 10 characters wide, each followed by a space, then a 2 digit decimal column.

```
wprintw(win,"%-10s %-10s %2d\n", "pizza", "spicy", 10);
```